# Why have I got banned just for 3 down votes? It doesn’t make sense!

Tags: discussion, support

I have asked 2 questions, one I got -1 down vote and second question, I got -2 down votes. And the suddenly, I got a message from a moderator that I have been banned.

What the heck is going on with this site??? To me it doesn’t look fair.

Yeah, I understand that if I get too many down votes for too many questions instead of 2 questions. I would understand this, but now? Really.

According to my logic, moderators should ban a user when that user have too many down votes for each question. But not for 3 down votes. It is not right.

**Why did a moderator banned me just for nothing and unfairly?**

Answer (score 10):

First of all, if you read the message you got again, you will notice that ***no-one* has been banned for *anything* there**. It is simply a little heads-up to take a little more care when asking future questions.

Now, why did you get this message? Since you ask, no, it's not just 2 questions and it's not just 3 downvotes. To be precise, you asked 10 questions on the main site so far:

- 60% of your questions have a negative score
- 60% of your questions have been closed, and
- 40% of your questions have been deleted

(those sets do overlap, and are sure correlated).

This is a pattern that's at least a little alarming and if anything, shows that you might be **struggling a little with asking questions**. Is this reason for moderators to ban you? Probably not, but it's worth a notice to maybe remind you of working on your questions and understanding of the site a little more.

However, I notice that you (more or less) coincidentally ***also* triggered an *automatic* question ban**. However this is not moderator-initiated rather than automatically and is not *directly* related to the message (although, ultimately for pretty much the same reasons). But it also shows that you haven't actually encountered that block yet, so this can't be what you're asking about here. To learn to get rid of that automatic question ban, you can take a look at [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/162011), which presents the same general advice as the moderator message you got.

Comment: Lol. How do you calculate and find the exact percentage?

Comment: @AlexA By...dividing the number of questions corresponding to the ciriteria by the total amount of questions. In this case this amounts to dividing a 1-digit number by 10, which...is just about doable with the Windows Calculator. ;-)

Comment: I think I understand you.